# Ubuntu bash if lessthan else condition returning error [: -lt: argument expected

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am doing the following script to know if profit or loss from entered selling price and cost price as;

```
echo enter selling price
read sprice
echo enter costprice
read cprice

if [ $sprice -lt $cp ]
  then 
    echo Loss
else
  echo Profit
fi
```

All the time, it is returning `Profit` , with an error code, like;

```
:~/shell$ sh shellb.sh
enter selling price
10
enter costprice
20
shellb.sh: 6: [: -lt: argument expected
Profit
```

what might be the reason, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Feel free to take a look at: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `$cp` variable to `$cprice` which is what you read in the line that says `read cprice`.

```
echo enter selling price
read sprice
echo enter costprice
read cprice

if [ $sprice -lt $cprice ]
  then 
    echo Loss
else
    echo Profit
fi
```

The script returns Profit even if `$sprice` has the same value as `$cprice`, so to be accurate add these lines to your script:

```
elif [ $sprice -eq $cprice ]  
  then   
    echo Break\ even
```

So what you end up with is:

```
echo enter selling price
read sprice
echo enter costprice
read cprice

if [ $sprice -lt $cprice ]
  then 
    echo Loss
elif [ $sprice -eq $cprice ]  
  then   
    echo Break\ even
else
    echo Profit
fi
```

Comment: I know, I was waiting for the time cap, I am active in SO and I know how this community run :)